# Chart.js not working on Angular 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm doing some tests with Angular, and wanted to try this cool library to make a test applcation, but it's not working:

> ReferenceError: Chart is not defined  angular-chart.js:13:5 Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=chartist&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0-rc.1%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dchart.js

This is my HTML template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app="chartist">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF8">
      <!-- Plugins/Frameworks !-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/angular.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/angular-route.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/angular-chart.js"></script>

      <!-- JS !-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers.js"></script>
     <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/directives.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services.js"></script> !-->

      <!-- Stylesheets !-->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/angular-chart.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div ng-view>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And I inject the dependency in the module by this way:

```
var app = angular.module('chartist', ['ngRoute', 'controllers', 'chart.js']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/index', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/index'
    });
}]);
```

Why can't I use Chart.js? Is some version problem? I will be glad is someone helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you closely look at error, it does clearly said that

> ReferenceError: Chart is not defined angular-chart.js:13:5 Error:
>   [$injector:modulerr]

Basically `angular-chart.js` doesn't work stand alone API. It is just wrapper directive to make it compatible very easily with AngularJS code. If you look at angular-chart.js code, you will come to know that it uses `Chart` object, which is come from `chart.js` API.

To fix you problem you need to add [**chart.js**](http://www.chartjs.org/) reference before `angular-chart.js` as, `Chart` object will available render chart.

So do add [**`chart.js cdn reference`**](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.js) reference before `angular-chart.js` to make your code working.

I'd also prefer you to go through the angular-chart.js Getting started Doc

[**Sample Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Lxkt4eyjMavRIJ0p838R?p=preview)

Comment: Sincerely, I don't understand this answer. Can you extend it a little?

Comment: Thank you, now it's much clearer! Also, it's working fine. I thought that angular-chart.js was standalone. Thx ^^

Comment: @Zerok Look at the getting started link, they have specified API dependency there. Anyways .Glad to help you.. Thanks :)